# How to solve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error compiling shader in Android Libgdx project?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am creating a game in Libgdx, For interaction with android UI, i have created interface and called the super implementation of methods in the classes, In Main Activity of android i have used the method implementation and added the android code.
I am facing this error when i try to run it?

This is the interface class and its method to go to android class

```
public interface abcInterface {

public void method1();
```

}

In Libgdx i am calling this method

```
game.method1(int a,int b);
```

In main activity i am calling this Interface method implementation

```
public void showmethod( final int level, int score)
{
    interface.method1(a,b, new interface() {

        @Override
        public void clickplay() {

            //...............
.................//

     }
    });
}
```

I am trying to call the callback method, but i am facing this error, need some suggestion and solution.

Comment: Please format your question properly and fix the code in the last code sample. What you wrote there is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your showmethod() with the below code, I hope your problem will be solved.

```
public void showmethod(final int level, int score) {
    interface.method1(a, b, new interface() {

        @Override
        public void clickplay() {
            Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //............... do your stuf here ................. //
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are the man. Saved me. I wanted to know why this issue occurred in the first place

Answer (score 0):

this is your interface

```
public interface abcInterface {

            public void method1();

            }
```

make a object of your interface like this

```
abcInterface abc = new abcInterface() {

            @Override
            public void method1() {
                // do here whatever you want 

            }
        };
```

now you can call method the interface like this

```
abc.method1();
```